# Typescript - Issue with Grunt-TS, Grunt, watch/compile, and dropbox

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, typescript, npm

**UPDATE**: After another computer started having troubles watching and compiling I think it may have something to with the tscommandxxxxxx.tmp.txt files that get generated as compiling happens...sometimes they arent removed when its done and other times they never appear

**UPDATE 2**: I think this occasional error might play a part:
`Error happened in chokidar: { [ Error: EONOENT, stat 'C:\Users\me\dropbox\xxx\xxx\myApp\src\.subl3cb.tmp'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'C:\\Users\\me\\dropbox\\xxx\\xxx\\myApp\\src\\.subl3cb.tmp' }`

When I go looking for that temp file its not there so I cant attempt to read it. I don't know anything about chokidar besides that its a dependency of `grunt-ts`

---

I have been working with Typescript (0.9.5) using Sublime (not VS) with node/npm, `grunt`, and `grunt-ts`. Grunt/Grunt-ts was setup to watch a directory for changes to `.ts` files and then compile them to `.js`. All the project files including the local npm modules are stored on dropbox and each computer I develop on also has `grunt-cli` installed globally. Everything was working great for a couple weeks and then last week I saw that Typescript 1.0RC was available so I attempted to change the `grunt-ts` dependency from 0.9.5 to 1.0 to see if it would work. Well it didn't so I uninstalled `grunt-ts` and re-installed it. It still works fine on 2 of my 3 PCs but for some reason my main one (the one where I initiated the changes) will not successfully watch the directory and recompile anymore. I have uninstalled node, removed the npm modules directories I could find (one where node was installed and then 2 under appdata/roaming - one of which was a cache folder) and then re-installed only the things I have on the other PCs, but it didn't make a bit of difference. The most annoying part is that there are no errors it just simply sits there after the initial compile that happens when I run `grunt` from the project folder...never updating on file changes...If I run `grunt` on another pc and make file changes, once dropbox syncs that PC watches and compiles fine.

Aside from trying to find somewhere where some old npm/node info is cached, I am out of ideas on what to try...

Even though it shouldn't matter since it works on other PC's via dropbox, here is the gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    "use strict";

    grunt.initConfig({
        ts: {
            options: {
                target: 'es5',
                module: 'amd',
                sourcemap: true,
                declaration: false,
                nolib: false,
                comments: false
            },
            dev: {
                src: ["src/**/*.ts"],
                watch: 'src',
                outDir: 'src'
            }
        },
    });

    //load the task
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-ts");
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["ts:dev"]);
};
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-ts": "~1.7.2-2",
    "typescript": "0.9.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling and reinstalling everything node related at the global level, I decided to do the same within the project...I did everything many different ways but always go the same result.

So I realized I had a tiny tutorial project elsewhere on dropbox and ran `grunt` for that project and the watching/compiling worked! I remembered that I had copied the `gruntfile` and `package.json` directly from that project when I started so they were identical as were the `npm` packages and directory structure.

Finally, I deleted my larger app's `node_modules` folder and copied the `node_modules` folder from the working tutorial over in its place....and it magically works...well not magically, it turns out that the old project was using `grunt-ts 1.6.4` and at some point during my attempt at upgrading the TS version I updated grunt-ts which for whatever reason does not work for me at 1.7.2-2.

Comment: Can you try running it with the watch test that comes in the `grunt-ts` repo? Uncomment this line : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L180 and run `grunt ts:fail` and try and edit a file. Does it get watched for you?

Comment: PS: I'd be happy to look at your project if you can post it on github or private repo inside bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

> Typescript 1.0RC was available so I attempted to change the grunt-ts dependency from 0.9.5 to 1.0 to see if it would work

You don't need to modify `grunt-ts`'s internal `package.json`. You can do it from your `package.json`: 
https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#alternate-compiler-version

e.g.:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt" : "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-ts" : "~1.7.2",
    "typescript" : "0.9.7",
  }
}
```

About:

> old npm/node info is cached

grunt-ts has none.

Can you share your package.json? Try the latest version of grunt-ts (`1.7.2-2`) if you can.

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt" : "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-ts" : "~1.7.2-2",
    "typescript" : "0.9.7",
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply I added the package.json above. However, I do not think this is the issue because my other two PCs are using literally the same package.json and gruntfile since they are stored on dropdox. PS - I love your vids on youtube about typescript and angular!

Comment: it looks like another computer has stopped watching/compiling..I think I saved again while it was still compiling, it threw and error and then stopped working. I think a .tmp file was an issue.

Comment: I think something with chokidar dependency is the issue.

Comment: I am not sure what all happened in the 1.6.4 to 1.7.2-2 upgrade but I can not cleanly install grunt-ts 1.7.2-2 and the error seems to be with rebuilding node-gyp and chokidar. Let me know if you want me to log any issue on the grunt-ts github

Comment: If you are getting a fsevents error you can safely ignore them. I just created an issue to track though : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts/issues/71